# Why are variables not changed and objects are after assignment in a function?

Tags: php

I found that a common var `$g` can't be changed in a function; but object `$e` can be. Why?

```
<?php
class e {
    public $var1 = 1;
}

function f($e,$g) {
    $e->var1 = 2;
    $f = 2;
}

$e = new e;
$g = 1;

var_dump($e->var1);
var_dump($g);

f($e,$g);

var_dump($e->var1);
var_dump($g);
```

result:

```
int(1)
int(1)
int(2)
int(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are passed and assigned by reference.

So when you change the 'parameter' variable, you're also changing it's original value.
This does not happen with other parameter types (strings, ints, arrays), but only with objects.

For more details, read [References and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

Also, I belive there's a typo in your `f($e,$g)`: shouldn't it be `$g = 2`?

If you need to tamper with the object but still keep a copy it's original value, do a `clone`:

```
$b = clone $var;
```

becase:

```
$b = $var;
```

will result in the same thing. `$b` will still point to `$var` and all changes on `$b` will reflect on `$var`;